# Regular Expression for Full Name(must be two words or more)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have tried to define a regular expression for the full name of person, in the form: "Deepak Das" or "Deepak Bidyabhusan Das". The name must contain at least two words like the the ones above, and it must not permit single word name like "Deepak" or "Roger" etc. I have tried a lot, but none of the expressions seem to be working.

These are the expressions I have tried so far:

```
^[a-z A-Z]+$---> this one is allowing any word names  
^[a-zA-Z\s]+$  
^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$  
^[a-z A-Zs]+$,  
^([a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z])+$ ---> this one is allowing only three word or more.
```

Could you please explain what I may have done wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). #5: "People have exactly N names, for any value of N."

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's elaborate rules first:

1. Each part of a name *must* start from capital letter `[A-Z]`.
2. Each part *can* contain small letters `[a-z]`.
3. A name *must* contain at least 2 parts separated by `\s`.

Examples:

```
  John Smith
  George W Bush     // please, notice "W" 
  Shi Li Hoi Kuang  // four parts
```

So the pattern can be

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(\s[A-Z][a-z]*)+$
```

But, please, remember that *real peoples' names* can vary, e.g.

```
 Charles de Batz-Castelmore d'Artagnan
```

notice `-`, `'` and `d'`; it's a *challenging task* to provide a relevant *set of rules*, let alone regular expression for them.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
 ^([a-zA-Z]*)\s+([a-zA-Z ]*)$
```

It captures the first name and the second names separately. It won't match a single name on its own. Here is a live example of this regular expression: http://rubular.com/r/aux8CsJsKw

If you want to capture multiple first names and a single surname, go with:

```
^([a-zA-Z ]*?)\s+([a-zA-Z]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

Use this expression

Answer (score 0):

**This does not work**
Leaving it here for context

```
^(\w+ ){2}
```

The `\w` matches any letter or number, the `+` says that you can have as many of this next to each other as you want. The space is just that a space and the `{2}` says that the funciton `w+`needs to be 2 times.

**Edit** this should work

As @Draken pointed out it will need a space after the second word.

So a more simple approach would be:

```
^\w+ \w+
```

Just a word, a space and a word

**Edit2**

Another correction, I didn't saw it may be more than 2 words.

```
^\w+( \w+)+
```

And for them to start with a capital letter:

```
^[A-Z]\w+( [A-Z]\w+)+
```

Comment: But that won't allow `Fred Jones.` as it doesn't have a space at the end of the name.